# How to make a java infix to postfix while including spaces

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java class that allow the user to put in space when putting in the tokens for the calculator and then turns it into postfix.

But it is not giving the correct output.  For example, for an input of `1+2`, the output should be `12+` but it is `12`.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Infix
{
    Stack loco = new Stack();

    //create a scanner
    //now to create a stack
    public String Prefix(String gordo)
    {
        //Here is where the Program Begin   

        //type the the regular expression
        String[] red;
        red=gordo.split("(?=[()+\\-*/])|(?<=[()+\\-*/])"); //tokenize the string include delimiter
        System.out.println("THE EXPRESSION IN INFIX IS");

        for(int k=0;i<red.length;k++)
        {
            red[i]=red[i].trim(); //remove white spaces
        }

        //now we will test out if what is stored is digit or character
        System.out.println("BREAKING IT ALL DOWN INTO A STRING OF CHARACTERS");
        String ramon;
        char[] c; //an array of characters
        char feo; // a single character

        String post=""; //this is where the post fix expression will be put in

        for(int i=0;i<red.length;i++)
        {

            ramon=red[i];
            c=ramon.toCharArray();

            for(int j=0;j<c.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(c[j]); //print what is stored in C
                feo=c[j];

                if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(feo) == true)
                {
                    post=post+feo; //add character to string to post fix

                }
                else if( feo == '(' )
                {
                    loco.push(feo);
                }
                else if( feo == ')')
                {
                    char look;
                    while((look = LookAt()) != '(')
                    {
                        post=post+look; //add it all in there
                        PopIt();
                    }


                }
                //this does the associtivity and the operator precdence
                //if the operator is lower or equal to the precedence change
                //the current operand pop it from stack and put it into output
               //string
                else 
                {
                    while(LaPrio(feo) <= LaPrio(LookAt()))
                    {
                        post=post+LookAt();
                        PopIt();

                    }

                }

            }
        }


        System.out.println("THIS IS THE POSTFIX EXPRESSION");
        return post;

    }


    //this will determine operator precedence 
    private int LaPrio(char operator)
    {
        if(operator == '/' || operator == '*' || operator == '%')
        {   
            return 2;
        }
        if(operator == '+' || operator == '-')
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;

    }

    //this will do the see what is one top of the stack
    private  Character LookAt()
    {
        if( !loco.empty() == false) //if there no items it will return false plus ! make it true
        {
            return(Character) loco.peek();
        }
        else
            return 0;


    }

    private  void PopIt()
    {
        if(!loco.empty())
        {
            loco.pop();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please edit your question to include 2 first line in code part

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's not working"?  What's going wrong? Perhaps you could provide some sample input, show us the output you expect, and then the output that you really get?  Honestly though, I think the best thing for you to do would be to step through this with a debugger.

Comment: For example I put 1+2 I should get 12+ but I get 12

Comment: @jameschol do you want another code that working not this one?

Comment: sure I just need the infix to postfix as seperate class

Comment: Look at your code again.  You don't put anything into the stack unless you encounter `(`.  So all the part about looking at the stack doesn't get used.  All that's left is the part about copying letters and digits to the output expression.  That's exactly what's happening.  There's no code to copy the `+` character, so it simply doesn't get copied.

Comment: @David wallace Hmm you are right let me see

Comment: I think on my last last else statement right after if I would need to put loco.push(feo); that is push in my token.

Comment: `(!loco.empty() == false)` is the same as `(loco.empty())` and considerably less readable. Don't write code like this.